# Unprotected sheet cannot be modified

Tags: vba, excel, password-protection

I have a sheet  that I protected with password. When I change anything on that sheet with VBA I unprotect like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="pass"

    'do stuffs

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="pass"

End Sub
```

The problem is that I still get this error message in this line:

```
 For j = 13 To 12 + numberofsomething
     With Range("H" & j & ":L" & j).Borders
         .LineStyle = xlContinuous  '<---Here
         .Weight = xlMedium
         .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     End With
 Next j
```

> Run-time error: 1004
>   Unable to set the LineStyle proprety of the Borders class

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you show a bit more code please to show how the second block of code is being executed?

Comment: The block code that I copied is in an If statement, like that:
 If target.Address = "$H$5" Then .....

End If

Thats all

Comment: Is that in the `Worksheet_Change` procedure?

Comment: Yes, it's in that procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not efficient to Protect and unprotect your Worksheets every Time.

You can Protect all of your Sheets Like that:
Sometimes Excel get a Problem if you have allready a Border, so just set the B order to None Before you Formating it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim wks As Worksheet

  'Loop over all Sheets
  For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    wks.Protect Password:="Secret", _
     UserInterFaceOnly:=True
  Next wks

End Sup
```

The UserInterFaceOnly is an optional argument of the Protect Method that we can set to True, the default is False. By setting this argument to True Excel will allow all Excel VBA macros to run on the Worksheet that protected with or without a password. So you don't need to Unprotect your Worksheets all the Time.

And to your Other Problem, Excel sometimes gets Problem When the Borders are allready set. So try to set the Borders to None before Change them.

```
For j = 13 To 20
    With Range("H" & j & ":L" & j).Borders
         .LineStyle = xlNone
     End With
     With Range("H" & j & ":L" & j).Borders
         .LineStyle = xlContinuous  '<---Here
         .Weight = xlMedium
         .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     End With
 Next j
```

Comment: I have already tried the UserInterfaceOnly mode, but it's only work till i reopen the workbook. After that, the password is active, but the macros cannot change cells value.

The second part of your comment is true, but the strange thing is, that in the other part of the code setting borders when already set has no problem with that.

Comment: @PyVa That's why you need to Insert the Loop With the UserINterfaceOnly to the Workbook Open Event in ThisWorkbook. So the Code will be Executed by every Opening of the Workbook.

Comment: @PyVas Does it Work in your Code if you Set the Borders to None in your Rutine or comes the Error Aswell?

Comment: I already tried in the Open Event way, but it is very-very slow in Excel 2010 because Encyption Algorythm is so slow. It takes a half a minute, which is unacceptable.